# Api One signal that return app state (active or incative)

Tags: notifications, onesignal

I developed an app with multiple screen .

In one of thease screen user is receiving real time messages.
If he is not in this screen he will not receive message and maybe miss a lot of imoprtant message .

I am using one signal for notifications .

Is there a one signal api that return if the app is on screen message or not to send a notifaction  with the message   ?

Answer (score 0):

```
https://onesignal.com/api/v1/players/PLAYER_ID?app_id=APP_ID


{
"id":"b186912c-cf25-4688-8218-06cb13e09a4f",
    "identifier":"ce777617da7f548fe7a9ab6febb56cf39fba6d382000c0395666288d961ee56    6",
 "session_count":1,
"language":"en",
 "timezone":-28800,
 "game_version":"1.0",
 "device_os":"13.6.1",
 "device_type":0,
  "device_model":"iPhone12,1",
  "ad_id":null,
  "tags":{"a":"1","foo":"bar"},
  "last_active":1598826147,
  "amount_spent":0.0,
  "created_at":1395096859,
  "invalid_identifier":false,
  "badge_count": 0,
  "sdk":"021502",
  "test_type": null,
  "ip": "2601:647:4b04:690:216a:4637:f37c:53ab",
  "external_user_id": null
 }
```